# Sencha cmd build failing while working with EXTJS6

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am working with EXTJS6 and sencha cmd 6.1.2.
I am trying to run the sencha app build on my application and getting below exception for which I do not have any clue.

```
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (missing ] after element list =>             MyApplication.view.testPack,) -- unknown-uri:81:59


[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: failed optimizing C:\git2\xx...{MyapplicationName}
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.ast.AstUtil.parse(AstU
[ERR] til.java:70)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 15 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
```

I manually removed some errors resulted due to '&' in the object key as the compiler does not like it. But for this error I dont have clue. Specifically, the error command does not tell me which file the error has resulted from?

```
**`[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (missing ] after element list =>             MyApplication.view.testPack,) -- unknown-uri:81:59`**
```

Has any one faced similar issue or any pointers pls?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you don't post the relevant code?

Comment: The issue is in the file `MyApplication.view.testPack`, which has a **syntax error** that exhibits in line 81, character 59. Syntax errors are the easiest-to-find error you can have. Every browser should give you a syntax error in that line whenever you load that JS file.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - Sorry. There was an issue with the filename which was causing the build failure. Could not post any code due to policy and since it was very generic

Comment: @Alexander - Yes, It was the filename, which was causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, I could not post the problematic code here due to the company policy but would like to post the issues which I faced. I hope, this will help someone.

1) Sencha Cmd does not like package/classnames having numeric values in it.
 - This is strange since the sencha site mentioned that classnames with numeric values are discouraged but allowed if it makes sense for an example `MyApp.form.Base64` // This is valid.

This was one of the reason why my app build was failing

2) I had a package name with a reserved keyword (which was a business requirement) - For an example `MyApp.default.form.LoginForm`.
Since default is a reserved keyword, my build was failing.

Comment: Numbers in class names are fine, as long as they are valid JS identifiers.